# How to use tomcat in eclipe?

Tags: spring, tomcat

```
@PostMapping("/post")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public Hud uploadMultipartFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        File newfile = new File("C:/Ficheros/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
        file.transferTo(newfile);
            
            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                    .getPrincipal();
    String username = userDetails.getUsername();
            
            if (newfile.isFile()) {
                if(!file.getName().equals("winamax_positioning_file.dat")) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newfile.getAbsolutePath()));
                    String line =reader.readLine();
                    reader.close();
```

0

Can anyone suggest me the coding of state changes in react-redux, basically thing will be like this ,We will have STATES=[UNINITIATED,INITIATED,INPROGRESS,FAILED],with initial status as uninitiated, so I will have a button, which I will click and the initial state will be changed to Initiated and button will be disabled, also it will fetch some kind of response from bff API, so for now, lets consider it(hardcoded) as success: 200 request, so after this the state will be showing in progress and also a toast will be displayed, also it will show failed if it request a fail message from the bff API and the state will again be uninitiated, also the button will be disabled after the first click and will only been enabled if the status becomes failed.

Comment: Quite strange that someone else asked a question that contains exact same texts, and did it at the exact same time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71455934/state-changes-related-to-redux-redux

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the library is configured such that no one can send many requests to google. I want to send 1000 requests per day and to achieve that I have to add fake_useragent to module. I tried a lot but when I try to add fake user agent to header it gives error. I am not a pro so I must have done wrong myself. Can anyone help me add fake_useragent to module(people_also_ask). here is working code to get question/answer.

```
from encodings import utf_8
import people_also_ask as paa
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
while True:

    input("Please make sure the queries are in \\query.txt file.\npress Enter to continue...")
    try:
        query_file = open("query.txt","r")
        queries = query_file.readlines()
        query_file.close()
        break
    except:
        print("Error with the query.txt file...")


for query in queries:

    res_file = open("result.csv","a",encoding="utf_8")

    try:
        query = query.replace("\n","")
    except:
        pass

    print(f'Searching for "{query}"')
    
    questions = paa.get_related_questions(query, 14)
    questions.insert(0,query)

    print("\n________________________\n")
    main_q = True
    for i in questions:

        i = i.split('?')[0]
        
        try:
            answer = str(paa.get_answer(i)['response'])
            if answer[-1].isdigit():
                answer = answer[:-11]
            print(f"Question:{i}?")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        print(f"Answer:{answer}")


        if main_q:
            a = ""
            b = ""
            main_q = False
            
        else:
            a = "<h2>"
            b = "</h2>"

        res_file.writelines(str(f'{a}{i}?{b},"<p>{answer}</p>",'))

        print("______________________")

    print("______________________")
    res_file.writelines("\n")

    res_file.close()

print("\nSearch Complete.")
input("Press any key to Exit!")
```